# Database connection through proxy

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, proxy

I'm using entity framework 5.0 in my asp.net c# website project.

The database server is on a remote server, my developer machine is behind a HTTP proxy with LDAP authentication.

How can I configure my project to use specific proxy settings to establish the connection to my MSSQL server?

Comment: What kind of proxy is it? SOCKS5?

Comment: I've updated my answer. It's HTTP.

Answer (score 2):

Since SQL Server does not use HTTP communication natively, it will not work with an HTTP proxy (unless the proxy allows passthrough in which case it's really disconnecting itself from acting as a proxy and [this page may be of interest](http://www.example-code.com/sql/socket_http_proxy.asp)). Far form all HTTP proxies will allow this.

To expose data from the SQL server to your installation through an HTTP proxy, you may instead want to consider creating an [OData service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Data_Protocol) on the SQL server side, and use that for data access in your application. This will allow you to query the database over HTTP in a proxy friendly way.